# Display blank plot in shiny instead of error

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

When I have reactive data that gets passed to `renderPlot` (or other rendering functions), the data is often initially empty until some action happens.  The default rendering typically displays an error in the app before the action happens because the data is empty, ie

> Error 'x' must be numeric

in this example.  Is there some standard way to have the rendering functions act when they don't have data (maybe not rendering if there is an error or just being blank)?  I know I could go to the trouble of structuring all the reactive values so the output would be blank, but it seems like unnecessary work.

Example in rMarkdown shiny

````
---
title: "Example"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r}
shinyApp(
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
        inputPanel( 
            numericInput("n", "n", 10),
            actionButton("update", "Update")
        ),
        plotOutput("plot")
    )),

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
        values <- reactiveValues()
        values$data <- c()

        obs <- observe({
            input$update
            isolate({ values$data <- c(values$data, runif(as.numeric(input$n), -10, 10)) })
        }, suspended=TRUE)

        obs2 <- observe({
            if (input$update > 0) obs$resume()
        })

        output$plot <- renderPlot({
            dat <- values$data
            hist(dat)
        })
    }) 
)
```
````

Comment: If you place your output$plot inside the isolate it will only be created after the first call to update.

Comment: This post might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428130/r-shiny-how-not-to-display-plot-when-null

Answer (score 2):

Try surrounding the line that might error in a `tryCatch`. In your example, `hist(dat)` is what errors, so surround it like so:

```r
tryCatch(
  { hist(dat) }, # Code that might error goes here, between the { }
  error = function(e) {""} # Leave this line as-is.
)
```

That's telling shiny:

- try to run `hist(dat)`, and
- if you can't run it without an error, simply display an empty string instead.

Now there's no more error message and your histogram still works as expected.

#### Working example

Here's your MRE with the `tryCatch` solution implemented - scroll down to where the comment  says `# CHANGES HERE`; it simply replaces `hist(dat)` with the 4 `tryCatch()` lines - that's the only change.

````
---
title: "Example"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r}
shinyApp(
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
        inputPanel( 
            numericInput("n", "n", 10),
            actionButton("update", "Update")
        ),
        plotOutput("plot")
    )),

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
      

        values <- reactiveValues()
        values$data <- c()

        obs <- observe({
            input$update
            isolate({ values$data <- c(values$data, runif(as.numeric(input$n), -10, 10)) })
        }, suspended=TRUE)

        obs2 <- observe({
            if (input$update > 0) obs$resume()
        })

        output$plot <- renderPlot({
            dat <- values$data
            # CHANGES HERE (NEXT 4 LINES)
            tryCatch(
              { hist(dat) }, 
              error = function(e) {""} 
              )
        })
    }) 
)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exists` function to see if a variable exists before trying to plot it, and change it as desired otherwise:

```
renderPlot({
    if(exists("values$data")) {
      dat <- values$data 
    } else {
      dat <- 0
    }
    hist(dat)
})
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking for a way that avoids the checks and balances.  Just a way to have default rendering return blank instead of error.

Comment: This will depend on your actual plotting method - most R graphs won't give you a blank plot. ggplot2 graphs might work, using geom_blank or an empty data.frame. For your example above, I would set values$data <- c() to values$data <- 0 so you get a histogram at the opening of the app.