# R Shiny: How not to display plot when NULL

Tags: r, shiny

If you run this code in your R studio, you will find the plot for NULL data is still a huge block of white.

How could we not display it when data is NULL.

A large whiteboard doesn't look that good amid other charts.

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$x = renderPlot(NULL)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  plotOutput("x"),
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                            body {
                            margin: 0;
                            font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
                            background: #F2F0F0;
                            }

                            .shiny-plot-output{
                            max-width: 100%;
                            box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #888;
                            margin-left: auto;
                            margin-right: auto;
                            }
                            ")))  
  )

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this inside server.R:

```
  if(is.null(df)){}
  else{
  output$x = renderPlot(df)
  }
```

This would check if the data you are sending to `renderPlot` was NULL and only execute `renderPlot` if data exists.  This will probably make the canvas not appear as white, but the gray background.  Only issue is as you are making a shadow effect appear that that will also appear on the gray.

Comment: But plotOutput("x") in ui.R will error if the data is NULL and we cannot use if else statement in ui.R, right?

Comment: I don't notice any difference in the output after adding this text. @John did this solve your problem?

Comment: I used `renderUI` and `if` statement to dynamically adjust the height of the chart. This works pretty fine but is not very elegant since I have to wrap every chart with `renderUI`.

Comment: This doesn't work: "You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer". As @John says, I think this is caused by the fact the output expects an object that simply doesn't exist if (initial) df is NULL

Answer (score 5):

I have found an alternative solution (since the one above did not work for me). It makes use of the `shinyjs` package. Here is a minimal reproducible example.

```
library(shinyjs)
library(shinythemes)


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
                 useShinyjs(), # IMPORTANT, you have to call this function in your UI to use shinyjs
                 numericInput("num","Number", 5),
                 plotOutput("text1")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    observe({
      if (input$num < 5) {
        hide("text1")
      } else {
        show("text1")
      }
    })
    
    output$text1 <- renderPlot({
      plot(rnorm(input$num))
    })
  }
)
```

The plot is only shown if x > 5. Otherwise the plot (and the whitespace - highlighted here by using the `darkly` theme in shinythemes - does not exist)

Comment: at my end, once the plot is hidden, it does not show up again. even if you change the numeric input to >5.

Comment: is this solved? is there a way that the plot shows up again when x>5?

Comment: @Oshan i edited the answer, putting the condition test inside an observer. So the graphic appears again, when the number goes above 5 again.