# R Shiny: Can I use shinyjs() without an actionButton?

Tags: r, shiny, show-hide, shinyjs

I am hoping to hide a plot automatically with the use of shinyjs() without having to use an actionButton. Is this possible?

This is my code in ui.R:

```
tabPanel(title = "Plot", useShinyjs(), 
         sidebarPanel(width = 4,                                                                           
                      h2("Plotting"),                                                                           
                      radioButtons(inputId = "type",                                                                                                       
                                   label = "Type of Plot:",                                                                                                      
                                   choices = c("Scatter Plot", 
                                               "Pie Chart", "Bar Chart"),                                                                                                   
                                   selected = "Scatter Plot"),                                                                                  
                   ),

         mainPanel(width = 8,
                   br(), br(),                                                                  
                   div(id='showplot', plotlyOutput(outputId = "plot")),
                   div(id='showplot2', plotOutput(outputId = "plot2")),
                   br(),                                                     
                   h5(textOutput("description"))
                   )
                  )
```

This is my code in the server.R:

```
output$plot <- renderPlotly({
  if (input$type == "Scatter Plot") {
  show("showplot") 
} else {
  hide("showplot")
}
  ggplotly({
    p <- ggplot(data = variable_source(), aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y)) +
    geom_point(size = input$size, col = input$color) +
    labs(x = x(),
         y = y(),
         color = toTitleCase(str_replace_all(input$z, "_", " ")),
         title = toTitleCase(input$plot_title)

  if (input$fit == TRUE) {
    p <- p + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
  }
  p
  })
})

output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
if (input$type == "Pie Chart") {
    show("showplot2") 
  } else {
    hide("showplot2")
  }
  ggplot(shortlistpied(), aes_string(x = factor(1),  y = "Percentage", fill = input$y)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
    geom_text(aes(x = factor(1), y = label_pos, label = perc_text), size = 4) + 
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Oranges") +
    coord_polar("y") + 
    facet_wrap( ~get(input$x)) + 
    theme_void()
})
```

EDIT: This is what I see at first when I run the app : [scatter plot original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQryG.png), and this is all good. But when I click on the Pie Chart, I see this: [pie chart disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCreJ.png). The charts disappear when it should be there like this: [pie chart original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT4wR.png). Also, when I go back to click on the scatter plot, it disappears too like this: [scatter plot disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRmP4.png). Can this be resolved?

Basically, what I am trying to do is for the mainpanel to show the scatter plot when the user clicks on scatter plot and the pie chart when the user clicks on pie chart. I have tried using NULL but with reference to this post - [R Shiny: How not to display plot when NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428130/r-shiny-how-not-to-display-plot-when-null), it creates an uncomfortable white space and I hope to be able to avoid that.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: it's not a reproducible example. But I guess that if you wrap your plots in a div with a unique ID you can hide that div without creating the whitespace.

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your reply! I am sorry that it is not reproducible. I am really new to r shiny and I was wondering what you meant by wrapping my plots in a div. I am not too sure how to do that. Thanks once again.

Comment: `div(id='hidethisid', plotlyOutput(outputId = "plot"))`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply once again! Sorry, I am still a little confused. So I wrap my plots in a div (as above) in my ui. Then in my server, do I simply do    
`observe({
    toggleClass(id = "hidethisid", class = "plot", condition = input$type == "Scatter Plot")
  })` outside of my output$plot / output$plot2 functions?

Comment: That could work. It is hard to help if you don't post a fully working example.

Comment: So I am not too sure how to make it reproducible since I would have to change the dataset, but I have attached a series of screenshots above that I hope would help? I have tried to incorporate your code above but it still does not resolve the issue and I am not too sure why. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that this is all the code that you have in your server? Than there are a lot more issues

Comment: No no, there is a lot more but I figured that these are the relevant portions. I guess essentially what I am trying to ask is if there is a way in which I can 1) hide a plot output in the mainpanel when I click on a different input in the sidepanel; 2) replace that blank space with another plot output instead; and 3) for it to be able to revert to the original when I click back on it. Thanks!